# Alfresco with Drupal CMIS

Tags: drupal, alfresco, cmis

I am attempting to configure Drupal CMIS to connect to the Alfresco public test repository.

I am using this CMIS module
https://www.drupal.org/project/cmis

I am using Alfresco 4.x CMIS Content Repository as found here
https://www.alfresco.com/cmis

The problem is that when i try to browse the repository in drupal I get the following message
There has been an problem contacting the CMIS server, please see the logs.

The error log always reads

```
HTTP call to [repository link here, shown in code sample bellow] returned [307]. Response: Authentication Required Authentication Required
```

my Drupal settings file contains the following

```
$conf['cmis_repositories'] = array(
'default' => array(
'user' => 'admin',
'password' => 'admin',
'url' => 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/ws/200908/'
)
);
```

The config is copy/pasted from the modules documentation and includes the URL which appears in the error message. Also I have viewed the $conf global using print('

```
' .print_r($conf,true) . '
```

') so I definitely have settings.php correct.
is my admin, pass, url combination still valid (ie is the site up to date)
what else could be causing this?

Comment: Shouldn't the URL there be the URL of your Alfresco repository?

Comment: SWe don't currently have an Alfresco repository - we are using the public test one.

Comment: That still doesn't look like the URL of the public test Alfresco repository, that looks like the URI of the CMIS definition namespace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url seems to be wrong.

Please try with http://cmis.alfresco.com/cmisatom (Atompub ) , http://cmis.alfresco.com/cmisbrowser (json)

Links are there in the alfresco web link mentioned by you

cheers,

Saurav